gstreamer cant demux a .ts video but ffmpeg can. How can I fix the error?
I have a .ts video that when I run through a basic gstreamer pipeline I get an error that it can't demux the video.
comand:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="/videos/my_video.ts" ! tsdemux ! meta/x-klv ! fakesink

I get the error:
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
gst/parse/grammar.y(853): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstTSDemux named tsdemux0 to some pad of GstFakeSink named fakesink0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst/mpegtsdemux/mpegtsbase.c(1759): mpegts_base_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

When I run the same video through ffmpeg:
ffmpeg -i /video/my_video.ts -map data-re -codec copy -f data

I get out:
  Duration: 00:29:56.49, start: 1920.682267, bitrate: 1873 kb/s
  Program 1 
  Stream #0:0[0x21]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0x28]: Data: klv (KLVA / 0x41564C4B)

I've also been successful in extracting that klv data using ffmpeg to a .bin file and analyzing the klv data within it.
Though when the ffmpeg command runs it does also give me this error initially:
Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x15d004590] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x15d004590] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x15d004590] non-existing PPS 0 referenced

Which prints out many times before producing the results.  My understanding/theory is that the video is missing some keyframe data in the beginning and/or the start has a compression error of some kind, but thats just my guess.  Whatever the problem is, ffmpeg is able to handle it but gstreamer is not.
Is there anything I can do to the video or within gstreamer to handle what the error might be? Is there any other tests that I can do on the video itself that would point to some other causes?

Can you make the file available?

I can’t unfortunately.

Here's a ts file using MPEG2-TS with almost (h265, KLV PID 0x28) if anyone wants to try run it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tfm13Mqqxb18MXv5k3y_pBozGZJE6l9w/view?usp=sharing. You can check it with ffprobe -i file.ts confirm it has Stream #0:1[0x28]: Data: klv (KLVA / 0x41564C4B). Or with gstreamer: gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=file.ts ! decodebin ! autovideosink, and notice the older gstreamer works, as per my answer below.

I had this issue with the latest version of Gstreamer. I too have an RTP stream of MPEG2-TS, with 1 video stream, and 1 KLV stream with PID 0x28 (weird version of KLV?).
Downgrading Gstreamer to 1.22.12 fixes it for me. I've opened an issue on Gstreamer's repo: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/3896
The problem for me is I need to build it locally for other reasons, and 1.22.12 is difficult to build now compared to the latest releases.
